# How much should I rotate to eliminate the cross term for $C = \{(x,y) \vert 2x^2 - 4xy+5y^2 - 36=0\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

The curve $C = \{(x,y) \vert 2x^2 - 4xy+5y^2 - 36=0\}$ in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R^3}$. To eliminate the cross term, How much rotate $\theta$ as the counter-clockwise direction? ($0 \leq \theta \leq\frac{\pi}{2}$)

In my instructor's note, There was a question like the above. The answer was $\theta = tan^{-1}(2)$. But my answer was $\theta = tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})$.

Here is the grounds for my opinion.

For $A =   \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 2&-2\\ -2&5 \end{array} \right] $ and $X = \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} x\\ y \end{array} \right]$ , $X^tAX =36$.

Since Eigenvectors are $\frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 2\\ 1 \end{array} \right] $ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} -1\\ 2 \end{array} \right] $  for the $1$ and $6$ respectively, I found $P = \frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 2&-1\\ 1&2 \end{array} \right] $.

For the New cordinate system $U = \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} u\\ v \end{array} \right]$, $X=PU$

Substitute this on the equation of $C$ by $U^t D U$,  We get  $u^2 + 6v^2 = 36$. (Here $D$ is the diagonal matirx)

Plus from  $P$, $cos\theta =\frac{2}{\sqrt 5}$ and $sin\theta =\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$. Therefore the answer is $\theta = tan^{-1}(\frac{1}{2})$. In my personal view, The instructor have incorrect answer for this. Are my solution and answer right?

Appendix) The instructor's solution.

Eigenvectors are $\frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 2\\ 1 \end{array} \right] $ for the $1$ and $\frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 1\\ -2 \end{array} \right] $ for the $6$.

So the $P = \frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 1&2\\ -2&1 \end{array} \right] =   \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} cos\theta&sin\theta\\ -sin\theta&cos\theta \end{array} \right] $

Hence, $P^{T}= R(\theta)= \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} cos\theta&-sin\theta\\ sin\theta&cos\theta \end{array} \right]= \frac{1}{\sqrt5} \left[ \begin{array}{cc|c} 1&-2\\ 2&1 \end{array} \right]$ * $R(\theta)$ means rotation as much as $\theta$

The answer is $tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{cos\theta} = 2$

Comment: I agree that the answer should be $\theta = \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$, can you provide your instructors answer?

Comment: @Dragonoverlord3000, Thanks for your comment. I edited my post. :)

Comment: "in Euclidean space $\mathbb R^3$" - Clearly you meant the Euclidean plane $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: Is the matrix supposed to be $$P=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&\sin\theta\\-\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix},$$ or $$P=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\theta&-\sin\theta\\ \sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{bmatrix}?$$ I'll assume the former. That means your solution has the wrong sign; it should be $\cos\theta=2/\sqrt5$ and $\sin\theta=-1/\sqrt5$, thus $\tan\theta=-1/2$.

Comment: With that said, $\arctan(2)$ and $\arctan(-\tfrac12)$ differ by $90^\circ$. If a curve is aligned with the coordinate axes, then its $90^\circ$ rotation is still aligned with the axes. There is no problem; both are correct.

Comment: @mr_e_man,  Is it totally wrong when the assuming the latter, P(my case)? If so, would you tell me the reason?

Comment: Rotating clockwise is different from rotating counter-clockwise. You can rotate by $\arctan(2)$ in one direction, or by $\arctan(+1/2)$ in the other direction. You can rotate the curve to fit the coordinate axes, or you can rotate the coordinate axes to fit the curve; they're opposite rotations. Which form of $P$ is considered "counter-clockwise", or whether the rotation is considered as $P$ or $P^T$, depends on an agreement (e.g. between you and your instructor). It is arbitrary, but you must be consistent and stick to the agreement.

Comment: @mr_e_man, Ah yes! Thanks for your kind explaination :)